# Demonstration of a property I noticed for squares

Tags: geometry

Presuming we have a square with 2 opposite vertices known as having the cordinates (a,b) and (c,d), I  have noticed while looking over some cartesian coordinate systems that the other 2 verices would have the coordinates (d,a) and (b,c) -if between consecutive vertices all coordinates change or (a,d) and (c,b)-if between consecutive vertices only one coordinate changes. What is the mathematical explanation of this ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$: these two points definitely don't form a square with $(4,1)$ and $(2,3)$...

Comment: @MishaLavrov You're right. It seems that that if only one of the coordinates changes between consecutive points then we have (a,d) , c,b). Edited the question

Comment: What if the opposite vertices are $(1, 2) $ and $(2, 5)$ ?

Comment: I really shouldn't have asked this question while being this tired. I'll probably think of all the cases in the morning and then create a question that outlines all of them. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand your observation.

The center of the square would be at
$$\vec{c} = \left(\frac{a+c}{2}, \frac{b+d}{2}\right).$$

Let
$$\vec{v} = \left(\frac{a-c}{2}, \frac{b-d}{2}\right),$$
so that the $(a,b) = \vec{c} + \vec{v}$. Then, all you have to do to find the other two vertices you are looking for, is to rotate $\vec{v}$ by $90$ degrees in both directions:
$$\begin{align*}\vec{w}_1 &= \left(-\frac{b-d}{2}, \frac{a-c}{2}\right) \\ \vec{w}_2 &= \left(\frac{b-d}{2}, -\frac{a-c}{2}\right).\end{align*}$$

That is,
$$\begin{align*}\vec{c} + \vec{w}_1 &= \left(\frac{a+c-b+d}{2}, \frac{b+d+a-c}{2}\right) \\ \vec{c} + \vec{w}_2 &= \left(\frac{a+c+b-d}{2}, \frac{b+d-a+c}{2}\right).\end{align*}$$

For example, in the particular case where $\vec{c} = \vec{0}$, that is, $(a,b) = (-c,-d)$, you would have
$$\begin{align*}\vec{c} + \vec{w}_1 &= \vec{w}_1 = \left(-b, a\right) \\ \vec{c} + \vec{w}_2 &= \left(b, -a\right).\end{align*}$$
That is, you just have to rotate the vector $(a,b)$ by $90$ degrees.

Notice that rotating $90$ degrees is very easy:

> Just swap the coordinates and multiply one of them by $-1$.